# Defining 'N' Number of Dynamic Query Parameters in Swagger

Tags: json, api, swagger, query-string, swashbuckle

I have the scenario where an endpoint can accept 'N' number of query parameters with a non-predetermined name and value i.e. I have no idea what query parameters someone might pass in e.g.

```
?i=can&pass=anything&in=here
```

How would I describe the above using the Swagger [specification](http://swagger.io/specification/)?

Comment: Dynamic query params are now supported in OpenAPI 3.0 - see the ^^ linked Q&A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's not supported in the version 2.0 of the OpenAPI specification, but it may be addressed in future versions.

This [issue](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/349) and this [pull request](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/pull/804) can give you more details.